# Flutter 32-bit Android device - mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory

Tags: android, flutter, out-of-memory, heap-memory, 32-bit

This is only happening on 32-bit Android Devices while debugging and on release mode.
on another device, everything is working fine also on other platforms.

I can't able to find out why it is happening.
on Devtool I can only able to get `requestHeapSnapshot()` this info.
also added `android:largeHeap="true"` to the manifest file.

please help me find out why and where it is happening. how can I find that? how can I use devtool to find the cause of this issue?

also tried in profile mode. only log I got is the following script. and it is happening randomly.

```
[+218136 ms] W/Adreno-GSL(15074): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2461>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
[  +18 ms] E/Adreno-GSL(15074): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2236>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
```

```
Build fingerprint: 'xiaomi/ysl/ysl:9/PKQ1.181203.001/V12.0.2.0.PEFMIXM:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 5292, tid: 5409, name: 1.raster  >>> com.subbu.p_shop <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x1a
Cause: null pointer dereference
    r0  00000002  r1  00000003  r2  00000000  r3  a412e5c8
    r4  a9aefa58  r5  a9aef8e4  r6  00001f08  r7  00000000
    r8  a9aef600  r9  00000000  r10 00000000  r11 00000000
    ip  9c97e250  sp  8987b7d8  lr  9c137d0b  pc  9c138790
backtrace:
    #00 pc 0013f790  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxRenderBucket::AddUnbucketedEntries(EsxCmdBufType, unsigned int)+132)
    #01 pc 0013ed07  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxRenderBucket::BucketRenderingCmds(EsxRenderBucketParams*)+740)
    #02 pc 00172c5d  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::BucketRenderingCmds(int)+712)
    #03 pc 000d2ba7  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::BindDrawFramebuffer(EsxFramebufferObject*)+178)
    #04 pc 000a2cdd  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::GlBindFramebuffer(unsigned int, unsigned int)+332)
    #05 pc 01b9aba1  /data/app/com.subbu.p_shop-6wA9xoQ3OknHQqrmLioLXw==/lib/arm/libflutter.so (offset 0x188d000)
Lost connection to device.
```

Comment: What packages are you using?

Comment: auto_route:
  bot_toast:
  camera_windows:
  cloud_firestore: 
  csv: 
  cupertino_icons: 
  desktop_window:
  editable: 
  file_picker:
  firebase_auth: 
  firebase_core: 
  fluent_ui: 
  font_awesome_flutter:
  hive:
  hive_flutter:
  image_cacheing:
  image_compression:
  image_picker:
  isar:
  isar_flutter_libs:
  koukicons_jw:
  open_app_file:
  path_provider:
  path_provider_windows:
  pdf:
  platform_device_id_hap:
  printing:
  provider: 
  sentry:
  sentry_flutter:
  url_launcher:
  win32:
  window_size:

Comment: I suspect auto_route or isar. but it is working fine on 64-bit devices.

Comment: i also increased jvmargs. but still same response

Answer (score 0):

Isar does not support x32 platforms.

Comment: That version supports 32-it. there is no issue in db. I'm facing memory Issue

Comment: Isar also has many stability issues at the moment, so you're likely running into one of those. Also, just because it didn't say it doesn't support x32, like newer versions, doesn't mean it does properly.

Comment: Ok I will test the app without isar. Also is that error support to do with rendering